# How to install apache airflow from github

Tags: airflow

**Problem**: I want to install `apache-airflow` using the latest version of Apache-Airflow on Github with all the dependencies?

How can I do that using `pip`?

Also is it safe to use that in the production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this more useful:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git
```

It installs the latest version in development.

Comment: This command worked for me and I went from `v1.9.0` to `v2.0.0.dev0+incubating` just by running this command. I ran `sudo pip-3.6 install git+git://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git` since I'm using python 3.6. So the version I appear to have is the latest from here https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/releases

Answer (score 5):

Using pip:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git@v1-10-stable
```

Yes, it is safe.

You will need gcc.

Comment: Will this also install the extra features like `yum install airflow[all]` ? refer to https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html

Comment: @Fan yes the square bracketed extras also go right after the what you're installing, so `git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git@v1-10-stable[all]` same with removing the branch `@` or adding the egg name `#`.

Answer (score 4):

I generally use this

```
$  pip install git+https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git@v1-10-stable#egg=apache-airflow[async,crypto,celery,kubernetes,jdbc,password,postgres,s3,slack]
```

In this way I'm able able to install extra airflow features.