# why airflow errors out with "Can't connect to local MySQL server" and how to fix it?

Tags: airflow

I am running the Airflow 1.8 on CentOS host that is part of a Cloudera Cluster.

When I navigate to menu Data Profiling -> Ad-hoc query or Chart, I will always be prompted with error below:

**Chart:**
[image]

**Ad-hoc:**
[image]

What am I missing here? if this is due to some packages were not included in the installation, how can I add them now?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The solution for this problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61489605/4721514

Answer (score 0):

This can occur due to default configurations set in Airflow. Please verify that you are properly overriding your default connection settings either through [environment variables](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/howto/set-config.html?highlight=configuration), an `airflow.cfg` file or some combination of the two (though I recommend using just one method).

Comment: Can you rephrase your comment with more details and make it an answer? It is still not clear to me here. Thank you.

Comment: When you install Airflow you define connections to the backend either in the `airflow.cfg` or the environment variable overrides. You need to ensure that you are overriding these and pointing to a valid database. 

When I have seen this error in the past it is because we were not overriding the database connection.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I have in the cfg: `sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/mdivk/airflow/airflow.db`, any missing here?